# Facing issues while implementing @AspectJ with Spring 3.1.2

Tags: spring-aop

I am trying to implement logging with AOP on Spring 3.1.5 . But at run-time I am getting the following exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.manh.fm.bid.ejb.BidMgr' defined in class path resource [appCtx-fm.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.UnknownAdviceTypeException: Advice object [null] is neither a supported subinterface of [org.aopalliance.aop.Advice] nor an [org.springframework.aop.Advisor]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280)
    ... 89 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.manh.fm.bid.ejb.BidMgr' defined in class path resource [appCtx-fm.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.UnknownAdviceTypeException: Advice object [null] is neither a supported subinterface of [org.aopalliance.aop.Advice] nor an [org.springframework.aop.Advisor]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 91 more
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.UnknownAdviceTypeException: Advice object [null] is neither a supported subinterface of [org.aopalliance.aop.Advice] nor an [org.springframework.aop.Advisor]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.DefaultAdvisorAdapterRegistry.getInterceptors(DefaultAdvisorAdapterRegistry.java:88)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.DefaultAdvisorChainFactory.getInterceptorsAndDynamicInterceptionAdvice(DefaultAdvisorChainFactory.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport.getInterceptorsAndDynamicInterceptionAdvice(AdvisedSupport.java:482)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:188)
    at $Proxy136.getTransactionAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSourcePointcut.matches(TransactionAttributeSourcePointcut.java:36)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:227)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:264)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:296)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:117)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:87)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:359)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 106 more
```

Here are the details of my aspect class :

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {


    @Before("allGetters()")
    public void LoggingAdvice(){

        System.out.println("AspectJ Logging");
    }
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.manh.fm.kjb.MgrBean.processMyAction(..))")
    public void allGetters(){}

}
```

Here are the details of my spring context file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
<bean
        id="com.manh.fm.bid.ejb.BidMgr"
        autowire="default"
        class="com.manh.fm.bid.ejb.BidMgrBean"
        dependency-check="default"
        lazy-init="default"
         >
    </bean>
<bean id="loggingAspect" 
           class="com.manh.fm.aspectj.logger.LoggingAspect"/>
</beans>
```

The AspectJ related jars I am using along with related spring jars are 
**aopalliance-1.0,asm-all-3.0,aspectjrt-1.6.10,aspectjweaver,cglib-nodep-2.2.2**

Guys I am really stuck with this and I am new to Aop also , Please help me out with this !!!

Answer (score 1):

Try implement 'org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor', it is a 'subinterface' of 'org.aopalliance.aop.Advice', as suggested by the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue few day back , **org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean**

In my case it was an issue of old jars [My issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895963/aspectj-based-aop-with-spring-3-1)

can you try to run your app using latest jars:

```
aopalliance-1.0.jar
asm-3.3.1.jar
aspectj-1.7.1.jar
aspectjrt-1.7.0.jar
aspectjweaver-1.7.0.jar
cglib-2.2.2.jar
```